# FindWindow by class name not working?

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, mfc

To preface we have a strange requirement that all dialogs must be modeless for an MFC application. There is a particular dialog using region drawing and some custom controls to select dates and times for viewing past and future data per view. I need to be able to close this window when it loses focus, the main app gets a system command, etc.

I figured the easiest way to do this would be to register the class like so:

```
    // for CWnd::FindWindow
    WNDCLASS wndcls;
    SecureZeroMemory(&wndcls, sizeof(WNDCLASS));
    wndcls.lpszClassName    = L"CTransactionDialog";
    wndcls.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndcls.lpfnWndProc      = AfxWndProc;
    wndcls.cbClsExtra       = wndcls.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndcls.hInstance        = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
    wndcls.hIcon            = NULL;
#ifndef _WIN32_WCE_NO_CURSOR
    wndcls.hCursor          = AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_ARROW);
#else
    wndcls.hCursor          = 0;
#endif
    wndcls.hbrBackground    = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BACKGROUND + 1);
    wndcls.lpszMenuName     = NULL;

    BOOL retVal = AfxRegisterClass(&wndcls);
    if (!retVal)
        AfxMessageBox(L"AfxRegisterClass(CTransactionDialog) Failed");
```

Then later in response to various event handlers and messages where I would want these modeless window or windows to be closed to do something simple like this:

```
CWnd* pFound = NULL;
while ((pFound = CWnd::FindWindow(L"CTransactionDialog", NULL)) != NULL)
    pFound->DestroyWindow();
```

However despite the registration of the class succeeding and looking at `GetRuntimeClass` of the dialog in question in debug and seeing that is matches up as expected the `FindWindow` never seems to find or close these modeless dialogs as expected.

What am I doing wrong or is there a better way to go about this?

**Update:** This is how the dialog is created via a static method on the dialog class. The dialog resource for the id specified in create has the Popup property set which should resolve to `WS_POPUP` style under the MFC covers. The dialog shouldn't and doesn't have a parent as far as I knew.

```
CTransactionDialog* CTransactionDialog::ShowTransactionDialog(const CRect& crCtrlToFloatAbove, UINT dialogID, Itime defaultTime, Itime initialTime)
{
    CTransactionDialog* pCTDialog = new CTransactionDialog(crCtrlToFloatAbove, dialogID, defaultTime, initialTime);
    pCTDialog->Create(CTransactionDialog::IDD);
    pCTDialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

    return pCTDialog;
}
```

**Update:** Doh! `FindWindowEx` isn't finding anything either.

```
CWnd::FindWindowEx(AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL, L"CTransactionDialog", NULL);
```

However I have a new plan. I'm just going to make my own window message and handle it on the main frame. I think I can get away with passing a pointer to the dialog as the lParam of the message and then casting it to a `CWnd*` then calling `DestroyWindow`. It will work for most cases in a very round about way. I may run into trouble with minimizing and maximizing of the main frame window for dialogs that nothing is holding a pointer too but we'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the simplest and cleanest solution I could come up with:

```
BOOL CTransactionDialog::OnNcActivate(BOOL bActive)
{
    if (!bActive)
        PostMessage(WM_CLOSE);

    return CDialog::OnNcActivate(bActive);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`FindWindow` doesn't work with child windows. To find a child window, you can use [`FindWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing the HWND of the parent window as the first parameter.

Comment: `WS_POPUP` style on creation of dialog negates `WS_CHILD`. Do I need to specify that in the class registration as well?

Comment: Are you just using `Create()`? If so, then the windows will have your main application window as their parent.

Comment: Really? Even if the resource I'm using has the Popup specified in the properties which maps to `WS_POPUP` style on create? I'll post my code snippet for creation.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely the issue. From the docs for `CDialog::Create()`: "**pParentWnd**: Points to the parent window object (of type CWnd) to which the dialog object belongs. *If it is NULL, the dialog object's parent window is set to the main application window.*"

Comment: If you need a window to close when it loses focus implement a handler for the appropriate windows message and call `EndDialog()`.

Comment: @Chet: There is no call to `DoModal` so `EndDialog` would be a memory leak at best. @dlev Well then in that case I'll give `FindWindowEx` a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Class name denotes NOT the c++ class name - it denotes the window class name. This name was used to register the window by the OS and has nothing to do with the c++ class.

May [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574.aspx) enlight you...

Comment: He _is_ using the window class name.

Comment: I'm registering the window class using my class name. I probably could make it more unique but figured this would work.

Comment: I see - sorry for that - confusing.

Answer (score 0):

CWnd::FindWindow does not search child windows.

Is it possible that the mode less window that you are creating has a parent set and that is the reason why FindWindow doesn't find it ?

Comment: Can windows be child windows without the `WS_CHILD` flag or whatever it is? His window class doesn't have it.

Comment: The WS_CHILD is orthogonal to the style supplied to WNDCLASS

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% sure about this but I think you need to set your class name in the resource file. You are defining a windows class and creating a dialog class but you aren't linking them. Setting a class name in the WNDCLASS struct won't help unless you actually have a way of linking it to the dialog. If you use the resource file and define the dialog, and class name in there then it should work.